# Algorithm/function that returns random number in array in O(1) and creates single permutation

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, random, permutation

**Intro:** This is an interview question I had which I couldn't solve. A code solution will be good (in any language), but an algorithm/pseudocode is also great.

---

**The problem:** This problem is about designing an algorithm that solves the following problem:
You are given a function `int getRand(int x)` that gets an `int x` and returns an `int` in the range from `0` to `x` randomly (exclusively -> `[0, k)` ). Each call to `getRand()` is performed in *`O(1)`* time.
You are also given an array `int[] arr` of size `k` containing integers.

Write a function `getRandUnique()` that when called will return a *random* member from `arr` such that after `k` requests exactly you will have a full permutation of the members of `arr` (this actually means that `getRandUnique()` will return a **different** member of `arr` for each call).
Each call to `getRandUnique()` has to be performed in *`O(1)`* time.
You are allowed to use/store global variables etc...

E.g.: Assume `arr = [2, 3, 5 , 1]`. A call to `getRandUnique()` will return either `2, 3, 5, 1` in `1/4` probability. A consequent call to `getRandUnique()` will return on of the remaining `3` members in `1/3` probability and so on...

---

**Attempt:** I actually [solved this myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35242741/2204926) (after much trial and error) and posted the solution "Q&A Style". I would love to get some other possible ideas/solutions. I will accept any solution that works as the correct answer (I don't want to accept my own)!

---

**Question:** How can this be achieved with all the above restrictions?

Edit: Now I am aware that this problem corresponds to the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), even though the specifications are a little different/more strict here.

Comment: are pre-computations allowed? eg a-priori shuffle, then get sequentially with O(1)?

Comment: Everything is allowed as long as "everything" isn't more than O(1) (because that would defeat the purpose I guess)

Comment: People reporting this question as off-topic "why isn't this code working?", what exactly is the problem? This is a classic Q&A question and is completely on-topic on SO.

Comment: @Tunaki It would seem to be, once you associate "permutation" with "shuffle". But there are already 3 close votes as "off-topic" because, I assume, the pseudocode was included in an answer rather than in the question, and I don't wish to further their cause. Perhaps someone with a gold badge could mark it as a dup. :)

Comment: @beaker The pseudocode is in the answer *by design* as this is a Q&A question, hence not off-topic. Dup? maybe, not so clear because it is phrased extremely differently. I would let a mod decide

Comment: @Idos Oh, sorry I thought it was you who answered to me in the previous comments... Do you disagree with the dupe target? It seems like the answer is the same.

Comment: @Idos I agree with you. :) My suggestion was to keep this post around as a dup of the shuffle post rather than let it get closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Tunaki I don't believe it to be an exact duplicate because of the specific instructions. But I prefer not to cause a hassle/scene. So if you believe it's a dup then go ahead it's cool by me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is as follows:

- Define `index = 0`.
- Call and assign `index = getRand(k)` (remember that `k` is the size of `arr`).
- Swap `arr[index]` with `arr[k]`.
- Now call and assign `index = getRand(k-1)`. Now you can be certain that you won't get the index `k` again so you won't have to remove it.
- Swap `arr[index]` with `arr[k-1]`
- Continue doing this until you call the last `getRand(1)`.

Now you have an array `arr` that is a random permutation of itself as requested (don't even need an additional array).

Comment: You appear to have rediscovered the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle).

Comment: That's the right solution, but just a point on nomenclature: "Remove" generally implies a O(N) solution (basically moving everything after one forward) which is not what you want here (and which I'm sure you didn't have in mind). "Swap" is more appropriate

Comment: Hahaha nice catch! Apparently I reinvented the wheel.. Voo you're right, I will correct myself

Comment: Note that this assumes you are allowed to modify "arr".  If not, it becomes more interesting.. In that case if allocation of O(n) memory is considered O(1) then it is still solvable, otherwise it is not.